# How to mock useSWRConfig implementation?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, swr

Is there a way to mock implementation of `useSWRConfig` hook from SWR in Jest test?

```
import useSWR, { useSWRConfig } from 'swr';

it('should mutate', () => {
  const mutation = jest.fn();

  useSWR.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ error: true })); // this works
  useSWRConfig.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ mutation })); // TypeError: _swr.useSWRConfig.mockImplementationOnce is not a function

  expect(mutation).toHaveBeenCalled(); // not working
});
```

Docs: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation

Answer (score -1):

You can automock the `swr` module so that mock functions like `mockImplementationOnce` can be called on `useSWRConfig`.

Assuming you have the following React component.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useSWRConfig } from 'swr'

export default function TestComponent() {
    const { mutate } = useSWRConfig()

    return (
        <button onClick={() => { mutate('/api/user') }}>
            Mutate
        </button>
    )
}
```

You would mock `useSWRConfig` and its `mutate` function in your test as follows.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import { useSWRConfig } from 'swr'
import TestComponent from '@/components/test-component'

jest.mock('swr') // Automock `swr` lib

test('mutate is called', () => {
    const mutateMock = jest.fn()
    useSWRConfig.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ mutate: mutateMock })) // Make sure you mock `mutate` and not `mutation`
    // Using react-testing-library, but any other testing lib could be used
    render(<TestComponent />)
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Mutate' }))
    expect(mutateMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/api/user')
})
```